# Bootstrap 3 auto centering and auto padding the whole page by default?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

TB3 here, and here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/). As you can see, all the content (the header, the main body and the footer) seem to be contained inside something that is causing it to be padded + centered. I would like all this content to take up 100% the width of the page/viewport.

I *suspect* that it may have something to do with the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">

        ...
```

...perhaps these classes "auto-pad" and "auto-center" by default and need to be overwritten? Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the overall "container" to container-fluid that you have at the start of your document because that is what is containing and making it center.

```js
$('.orgSelector').dropdown();
   $('.orgSelector').tooltip();
```

```css
.acLogo {
 background-image : url("http://placehold.it/250x150");
}
.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.account-wall {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.login-title {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}
.profile-img {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.need-help {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.new-account {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
img.user-summary {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.user-summary {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
div.user-summary > img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
div.user-name {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
}
div.user-status {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand acLogo" style="height:auto; width:50%;" href="/"></a>
           </div>
           <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                           <li><a href="/features"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/compare"><b>COMPARE US</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/pricing"><b>FIZZBUZZ</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/company"><b>FOOBAR</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/docs"><b>DOCS</b></a></li>
             </ul>
             <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/app/dashboard/search" method="POST">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button></li>
      <li><a href="/app/dashboard">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Sign in</button>
      </a></li>
              </ul>
          </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </nav>
     </div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```